# Does SparkML CrossValidator re-fit to the full training data set after selecting the best hyperparameter combo?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cross-validation, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

After cross-validating a hyperparameter grid on a training dataset, does SparkML's `CrossValidator` re-fit to the entire training dataset? And if not, from what part of the cross-validation does it select the `bestModel` used for inference?

The fitted `CrossValidator` makes available a `.transform()` method. For this, does the `CrossValidator` re-train on the entire training/cross-validation dataset using the best hyperparameters and use that re-fitted model for inference?

Or is the `bestModel` used for inference the best performing model from across all cross-validation folds (that is, the model from the best fold from the best performing hyperparameter combo, trained only on the data for that fold)?

I ask this because of the superficial similarities between the SparkML `CrossValidator` and `scikit-learn`'s `GridSearchCV`. If you pass the parameter `refit=True` to `GridSearchCV`, it will re-fit on the entire training dataset using the best hyperparameters from the param grid. It then uses the re-fit model trained on the entire training set to exposes via the `.predict()` method.

I have read through [the Python docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator.html), [the Scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/CrossValidator.html), and [the examples showing hyperparameter tuning and cross-validation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html). I couldn't find any specific reference to this.

In the examples, there is the comment: `# Make predictions on test documents. cvModel uses the best model found (lrModel).` But from that it isn't clear whether it is the best fold from the best hyperparameter combo, or if it re-fits, a la scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning#cross-validation) it refits on the entire dataset after identifying the best fold:

> Cross-Validation
>
> CrossValidator begins by splitting the dataset into a set of folds which are used as separate training and test datasets. E.g., with k=3
> folds, CrossValidator will generate 3 (training, test) dataset pairs, each of which uses 2/3 of the data for training and 1/3 for testing. To evaluate a particular ParamMap, CrossValidator computes the average evaluation metric for the 3 Models produced by fitting the Estimator on the 3 different (training, test) dataset pairs.
>
> After identifying the best ParamMap, CrossValidator finally re-fits the Estimator using the best ParamMap and the entire dataset.